# PDO, check which condition(s) do not passed in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, pdo

Lets say that an user wants to edit his order in a online shop, but in the same time his order has being processed and the status of this order is set to "dispatched". Of course he can't really know that, because the order data was loaded just a while before it was dispatched. Now he can only get the message "Something went wrong..."

With a scenario like below, I can only send back to the user (via ajax) message that the order couldn't be updated (either the data wasn't changed or some of the values does not match in WHERE clause) :

```
   $edit_order = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE orders SET '.$some_fields_loop.' WHERE id=:order_id AND user_id=:user_id AND product_id=:product_id AND NOT status = :ready AND NOT archived = 1');

   $edit_order->bindValue( ... );

   $edit_order->execute();

   if ($edit_order->rowCount()) 
   {
       echo(json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'msg'=>'Your order has just been updated'));
   } 
   else 
   {
       echo(json_encode(array('status'=>'error', 'msg'=>'Your order has not been updated'));
   }
```

But I want to be more specific and let him know what's happened exactly (and eventually modify the order DOM elements, based on ajax response).

The **order_id** is wrong, or **user_id** because his session has just expired and the session[**user_id**] doesn't match the order, or so on... and send back to the user corresponding message.

How do I do this in single query? Is that even possible, or should I run each query with single WHERE clause seprately (what I would really like to avoid) ?

Comment: I would recommend writing a stored procedure. In these kind of circumstances they give you greater control in returning error messages for queries with multiple conditionals.

Comment: @IanBrindley are you serious?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes. SP's are not dead.

Comment: @IanBrindley you probably confused SP with something else.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not at all.

Comment: @IanBrindley SP won't give you something that regular query can't. You have a strange belief, but let me advise you to verify it against practice.

Comment: I'm not going to use SP's here (in a such relatively small app). As far as I understand, SPs could save me a bit of code writing but has nothing to do with performance - what is priority to me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id=:order_id
```

first, and then verify the result against desired values.

Comment: So, should I split it into two queries, **SELECT** and **UPDATE** (if it's updateable). And answering my question - there's no such functionality in PDO that allows me check separate WHERE condition (in multi WHERE clause), within one single query?

Comment: There is no "functionality" in PDO at all. PDO is just a proxy that takes your query, sends it to DB server and then relays back the result returned. Functionality you are talking about is functionality of DB server. To check anything you have to use SELECT query. To update something you have to use UPDATE query.

Comment: By saying functionality I meant a "tricky" query with joins and so on (don't know how to call it properly as I'm rather poor in advanced SQL. and english too) But why I ask - if 1000 users will operate on their orders in same time (I don't expect that, but who knows), it gives me double, 2000 queries in your scenario, therefore I always try to make as less as possible and was hope there's a way to do it single. But I got your point and understand.

Comment: That's a pity that such an imaginary condition is your concern. You have to problem at hand but you are ready to ruin your application trying to solve it.

Comment: "But why I ask - if 1000 users will operate on their orders in same time (I don't expect that, but who knows)" Premature optimization is evil. Deal with that if and when it happens.